# Does Percival have own resurrection powers and if so do they work in any circunstances?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

In the last episode of Nanatsu no Taizai, Percival apparently died (his eyes went blank) and apparently resurrected. The wikia mentions apparently resurrection powers and that he can heal from fatal wounds. If so, how far do they go, can he be killed?